# Isomorphism from Subspace to Subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is that:
If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, and $V_1$ and $V_2$ are subspaces of $V$ (both k-dimensional). How can I prove that there exists an isomorphism $L: V \to V$, where if $u \in V_1$, then $L(u) \in V_2$? I tried mapping a basis to a basis, but that didn't really work out...

Comment: **Why** did it not work out?

Answer (score 1):

For notation's sake, I am going to let the $k$ dimensional subspaces be $U$ and $T$. Now let $\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ be a basis for $U$. We can extend this to a basis $\{u_1,\dots,u_k,v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$ for $V$ from standard results. Similarly, let $\{t_1,\dots,t_k\}$ be a basis for $T$, and extend this to another basis $\{t_1,\dots,t_k,v_{k+1}',\dots,v_n'\}$ for $V$. What can you say about the map $\phi:V\to V$ defined by 
$$
\phi(u_i)=t_i,1\leq i\leq k \text{ and }\phi(v_i)=v_i', k+1\leq i \leq n
$$
and linear extension? Note that there are still things to verify here, this is not yet a complete proof.

Answer (score 0):

Since $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ are $k$-dimensional subspaces, they are isomorphic. Let $\phi:U_{1}\rightarrow U_{2}$ be an isomorphism, $\alpha=\{u_{1},...,u_{k}\}$ basis of $U_{1}$ and $\beta=\{v_{1},...,v_{k}\}$ basis of $U_{2}$ such that $\phi(u_{i})=v_{i}$. Extend $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to bases of $V$: $\{u_{1},...,u_{k},u_{k+1},...,u_{n}\}$ and $\{v_{1},...,v_{k},v_{k+1},...,v_{n}\}$. Then $\varphi:V\rightarrow V$ given by $\varphi(u_{i})=v_{i}$. It follows that if $u\in U_{1}$ then $\varphi(u)\in U_{2}$.